# inserting to mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have some data in cart and then I'm appending user_id to it. When I do `console.log(cart)` and `console.log(data)` I get user_id along with all other keys but user_id is not saved in the cart collection. Why is this happening and how can I fix it

```
cart.user_id = user_id
console.log(cart);
db.cart.insert(cart, function(err, data) {
   console.log(data);
   if (err) return next(err);
})
```

Comment: Which driver do you use? MongoDB or Mongoose?

Comment: @Mikhail I'm using mongoskin

Comment: Please Post your Db schema?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath there is no need of creating any schema in mongoskin